# How does hoisting work during the creation phase of context

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm trying to understand why this piece of code performs the way it does:

```
doStuff();
console.log(bar);

var bar = 'bar';

function doStuff() {
    var foo = 'foo'
    console.log(foo);
}
```

Output is:

```
app.js:9 foo
app.js:3 undefined
```

So my understanding here is that during the creation phase of the execution context, the engine sets up variables in memory but there's no assignment which is why `bar` is `undefined`.

What I don't get is why `foo` has been assigned and logging out a value during that same phase.

Some explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You are logging `foo` after it has been assigned. You are logging `bar` *before* it has been assigned. Clear difference, no?

Comment: @deceze yes i realise that but running the function before declaring it makes no difference then in terms of assignment within the function?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function doStuff() {
    var foo = 'foo'
    console.log(foo);
}

var bar;

doStuff();
console.log(bar);

bar = 'bar';
```

You can picture your code would be hoisted and interpreted in sequence that I've listed. During hoisting, only variable declaration will be hoisted but value assignment remain in same position. And hence when console logging bar will return undefined

Answer (score 1):

Function declarations are hoisted, function expressions are not.

```
isHoisted();

function isHoisted() {
    console.log("Yes!");
}

isNotHoisted(); // error

var isNotHoisted = function () {
    console.log("NO!");
}
```